# Describing personalities, saying colourful

Tags: grammar, meaning

How would I describe characters as being colourful ?

Would this be fine?:

とうじょうじんびつはいろがおおいです。

Also when describing a characters growth, would this sentence be fine?:

もじのせいかくはせいちょうするがいいです。

If it helps, I'm trying to say that the characters display good character growth.

Also what is the difference between とうじょうじぶつ and もじ

Comment: What do you mean by "colorful"? Something like [this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/girl-with-colored-face-painted-art-beauty-image/88614892), or like [this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/hero/11908031), or something entirely different? And could you share the full English sentence that you want to translate? BTW, もじ means character in the sense of "letter".

Comment: @naruto  To quote from a dictionary, I think the poster means someone who is `Full of interest; lively and exciting.` I don't think it necessarily has anything to do with their actual skin color/dress/makeup etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the question says "personality", but OP clearly said this "colorful" refers to one's physical color (clothing, hairstyle, etc) in his (deleted) comment. So I'll cover both.

#### Physically colorful (hairstyle, clothing, body paint, ...)

> とうじょうじんびつはいろがおおいです。

Yes this is acceptable except that じんびつ is a typo. It should be じん**ぶ**つ.

> 登場【とうじょう】人物【じんぶつ】は色【いろ】が多い【おおい】です。

But you could just use a loanword カラフル and say:

> 登場人物はカラフルです。

This may be fine if there is enough context, but it looks a little confusing because it's ambiguous (one colorful character vs. many characters with different colors). If there are many characters with different colors (like *Power Ranger*), consider 様々【さまざま】な色【いろ】の登場人物【とうじょうじんぶつ】がいます, which is unambiguous.

#### Colorful personality

色が多い ("has many colors") does not work here. Please try to rephrase it and find a better word/phrase using a dictionary. ("lively", "vivid", "cheerful", etc)

---

Lastly, 文字【もじ】 means character in the sense of "letter", "alphabet", etc.